# Creating Live Data for Auth Token in Account Manager

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-livedata

I am trying to create live data for the `authToken` in `AccountManager`.

This is how I am getting the auth token.

```
suspend fun Fragment.getAuthToken(): String? {
    val am: AccountManager = AccountManager.get(activity)
    val accounts: Array<out Account> = am.getAccountsByType(getAccountType())
    var authToken: String? = null
    if (accounts.isNotEmpty()) {
        val account = accounts.first()
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            authToken = am.blockingGetAuthToken(account, getAccountType(), true)
        }
    }
    return authToken
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#extend_livedata) I should do something like this:

```
class StockLiveData(symbol: String) : LiveData<BigDecimal>() {
    private val stockManager = StockManager(symbol)

    private val listener = { price: BigDecimal ->
        value = price
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        stockManager.requestPriceUpdates(listener)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        stockManager.removeUpdates(listener)
    }
}
```

However I can't figure out how to convert the example to match my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [another link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata)
you can use live-data builder for coroutine:

```
val token: LiveData<String> = liveData {
    val tokenValue = someYourFragment.getAuthToken() 
    emit(tokenValue)
}
```